# How to efficiently query one table to obtain a value I need to then change two dates on two rows in another table?

Tags: sql, firebird

I get the feeling this is easy for SQL, but I'm new to it. I want to query table `CUST_TRAN` and find out the `ID` for value $1 which is in column `INVOICE`.

I then want to use the newly discovered `ID` to update table `TRANSACTS` to change the `DATE` and `DATE_TIME` (two values in two columns) to value $2 using the column `IDFROMTRAN` to match the `ID` against. There are very often two rows with the same `IDFROMTRAN` that need to be updated, because the customer signs for the goods and that creates its own row.

Does any of this make sense?

Basically, to explain what I'm doing I'm changing the date on transactions to put them into last month, so that they'll be invoiced correctly and reflect when the customer was actually in store.

TLDR: How do I find out an alternative ID for a transaction then use that to change the date in two rows in another table?

Comment: Please provide the necessary DDL, example data and the desired result of the changes for that example data.

Comment: Consider `create`-ing your source `table`s and `insert`ing sample data rows at http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0

Comment: If "There are very often two rows with the same IDFROMTRAN", which one would be the correct value to reference? Earliest? Latest?? This would be much easier if you would provide sample DDL data.